# как при наведении на блок1 показать блок2 под ним но не дочерний

Tags: javascript, jquery

как при наведении на блок1 показать блок2 под ним но не дочерний 
и если уводим курсор с блок1 то блок2 скрывать,
а если при переходе  с блок1 на блок2 то блок2 не скрывать.

Comment: описание жесть, переформулируйте его и используйте запятые

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автор уже задавал идентичный вопрос и не раз...

Answer (score 2):

```css
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.block1 {
  background: red;
}

.block2 {
  display: none;
  background: yellow;
}

.block2:hover {
  display: block;
}

.block1:hover + .block2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1"></div>
<div class="block block2"></div>
```